# Implementing money.js on multiple fields on same page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cakephp

I'm struggling with conceptually how to implement this (what events to bind to etc).

I'm using CakePHP and have a view with the following:

- An array of products to display and an associated price ($products['Product']['price'])
- Each product has a base currency set ($product['Currency]['currency'])
- I have money.js, accounting.js and another JS that sets JSON data for fx.rates and fx.base
- I know the currency that the user wants to see and will likely differ from the product base currency (SessionComponent::read('User.Preferences.Currency')
- A div to display the currency shortname (USD) and converted value, each div with unique id

My simple test works fine - using inline-php I've put a bit of JS on the page between two script tags.

```
<script>
var value = accounting.unformat(<? echo $product['Product']['price'] ?>); // clean up number (eg. user input)
var target = "<? echo SessionComponent::read('User.Preference.currency'); ?>"; // or some user input
var convertedValue = fx(value).from("<? echo $product['Currency']['currency']  >").to(target);

accounting.formatMoney(convertedValue, {
    symbol: target,
    format: "%v %s"
}); // eg. "53,180.08 GBP"   

alert(convertedValue);
</script>
```

Fine. Works great. But what I can't work out is how to implement this on a page with N number of products.

I'm assuming I create a JS function, something like:

```
fx_convert(divid, price, fromcurrency, tocurrency)
```

And in my Cake view, I use inline php to echo the function parameters.

What is the clean way to use jQuery for this function, and have the price 'divs' call fx_convert and update their content with the converted value?

Or is my thinking totally backwards on this? All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you necessarily *need* to use jQuery, but it is useful sometimes. If you're using PHP and have all your data there, why not do your conversions there? Otherwise, your function idea would be the way to go.

Comment: I'm considering server side approach - but that is a different implementation. Keeping it client side gives me some more flexibility in UI in terms of changing currencies etc.

Comment: Oops - premature submit. I would have no problems writing the functional approach - my question is how do I trigger it..

Answer (score 0):

After some decent sleep, figured it out. :)

Using inline PHP, I pass the to/from currencies via the div attributes and set a uniform class name. e.g.

```
<div class="fx" fx-from="<?php echo $product['Currency']['currency']; ?>" fx-to="<?php echo SessionComponent::read('User.Preference.currency') ?>" fx-value="<?php echo $product['Product']['price']; ?>"></div>
```

And then use the following jQuery snippet to loop over all elements of class "fx" and do the required calculation (using the excellent money.js and accounting.js)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".fx").each( function( index, element ){

    var value = accounting.unformat($(this).attr("fx-value")); // clean up number (eg. user input)
    var target = $(this).attr("fx-to"); // or some user input
    var convertedValue = fx(value).from($(this).attr("fx-from")).to(target);

    $(this).html(accounting.formatMoney(convertedValue, {
        symbol: target,
        format: "%v %s"
    }));

});

});
```

Still need to refactor and tidy up, but the solution is there.